# Menus as per Role

Tags: navigation

A form which has two field Role and a Tree View Menu with checkboxes. I want to assign menus to role so that if a user with that role login the user would be able to see only those menus that have been assigned. The menu would be shown as dropdown to the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this module will do what you want: [Menu Per Role](http://drupal.org/project/menu_per_role)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Drupal 7, create different menus, one for each role. Then configure the menu blocks: place them in the same region and restrict each one to the respective roles through the `Configure` link.

Comment: @Paul...But I want that the uesr with Admin role will provide the menu to each role.... Basically I am working for an Intranet site which would be used as a product

Comment: The admin user (userid:1) IS able to configure menu blocks and hence can "assign" menus to users as described above.

Answer (score 0):

As Joe suggested Menu Per Role module is best for you, it will give you "Restrict item visibility" option through which you can set the visibility for different roles,
i have used this module for the same purpose and it works fine for me.

Comment: Menu per role is To assign roles to Menu. With Menu per Role I have to assign roles to each menu. But I want that for each Role Menu should be assigned. So I want to create a form module where Role Field will be Dropdown and a TreeMenu with CheckBoxes would be there.  If I want to edit the Menu for a Role I should be able to assign it through Tree Menu

Comment: just goto admin/build/menu-customize/navigation in your site to edit the menu for different role.

Comment: All these things could be done by developers i.e. Super Admin but I want a user(non-developer) to be able to edit menu as per there role. Then How could I achieve this

Comment: then u have to install http://drupal.org/project/adminrole module and use this tutorial http://www.jesox.com/posts/admin-role-module-preview to go through all the steps needed to achieve your functionality.

Comment: But this module is for Drupal 6 and I am using Drupal 7